# Why do I see this error: no such column: number (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Users_Table WHERE number =?

Tags: database, sqlite, listview, logcat

I get this error when I try to delete an item from the ListView and the Database, how can I solve it? Thank you
This is the method:

```
public int deleteSelectedItem(String number) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int result = db.delete( DB_TABLE, "number = ?", new String[] {number} );
    return result;
    }
```

This is the call:

```
 userlist.setOnItemLongClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, final int position, long arg3) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.this );
            alertDialog.setTitle( "Elimina" );
            alertDialog.setMessage( listItem.get( position ) );
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton( "Elimina", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 db.deleteSelectedItem( listItem.get( position ) );
                  }
            } );
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    } );
```

Logcat:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: number (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Users_Table WHERE number = ?
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1496)
    at com.example.listviewsqlite.DatabaseHelper.deleteSelectedItem(DatabaseHelper.java:54)
    at com.example.listviewsqlite.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The error is clear: there is no column `number` in the table `Users_Table`. If you added the column by code in the table after you first ran the app, uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and rerun to recreate the database and th etable.

Comment: Check also your manifest for this line: `android:allowBackup="true"`. If it exists change it to `android:allowBackup="false"` and repeat the uninstall and rerun. If the problem is not solved try in a clean device. Also just to make sure post the create statement of the table.

Comment: Thank you. I uninstalled, the error no longer appears, but I have another problem. Now the item is deleted from the database, but not from the ListView. I had thought of solving the problem with "notifyDataSetChanged ()", but I don't know which element to concatenate it

Comment: I tried with "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ()", but it does not work

Comment: The ListView contains the items that you loaded from the table to the adapter. When you delete a row from the table it is not also deleted from the adapter. Delete it from the list that is attached to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Thank you! I solved it thanks to your help! :)

Comment: @forpas: I think a bounty was set for you to post an answer here!

Comment: @GMB for me? Why? I thought the problem was solved and there is no need for an answer.

Comment: @forpas: yes indeed it looks solved and OP confirmed that, but see the bounty message: *Michele wants to reward an existing answer.*

Comment: @GMB well, then there aren't any existing answers. So I guess the OP will have to clarify.

Comment: @forpas: I understand that as: *please post your comments as an answer so I can reward you*. But, yes, OP could clarify themselves, I might be on the wrong guess here.

Comment: I wanted to reward your answer. What did I do wrong?